# Cursor : Invalid property value

Tags: css, firefox, mouse-cursor

I've been looking for this for a long time now. All I've found doesn't work for me sadly.

My custom cursor won't work on Firefox, I've a beautiful "Invalid property value". Also in Firefox Developper Edition I've the same error but the cursor is displayed. No problem in Chrome, it's displayed without any error.

There is no problem with my PNG I believe, it's fit all the requierement to be compatible with Firefox.

The code is simple, I don't need to show you more.

```
body {
  cursor: url('cursor.png'), pointer;
}
```

And the `cursor.png` image:

[image]

**Edit:** It's looks like a css rules `body:not([id])` is showing up as I inspect element:

[image]

This rule is not in my CSS files and I've no idea what it is doing here. Any ideas how to remove it?

**Edit 2:** Found out that it's NoScript ( add-on ) on Firefox which force this css properties. Can't find a way to remove it though.

Comment: How do you get the error in Firefox? There's nothing in the console and the cursor works.

Comment: Hello, 

When I inspect the element : http://puu.sh/oWHUA/0b4b88ae0d.png
The problem is coming from the body:not([id]) which I never wrote it, and I have no single clue why it's here. 

If you have ideas, pls let me know !
Ps : CSS Files if needed http://puu.sh/oWIk7/ea1f9614f0.css

Comment: Is the site live yet? I can take a look.

Comment: Hello, I just found that the css properties was foreced by No-Script ( add-on on Firefox ).... 
It's look like I've found the problem, need to figure how to disable for website now !

Answer (score 11):

You should add 2 more parameters like this :

```
cursor:  url(cursor2.png) 2 2, pointer;
```

please read this mozila guide : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your answer !

The problem is coming from this property : 

body:not([id]) {
    cursor: auto !important;
}

Which is not included in my css but still show as I inspect element : http://puu.sh/oWMAA/caaf9701b8.png

If you have any ideas about this.
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. Fixed it by adding "`auto`" to the end:

```
cursor: url('cursor.png'), auto;
```

Comment: The fallback is required for. As per MDN: "This means that zero or more URLs may be specified (comma-separated), which **must** be followed by one of the keywords defined in the CSS specification, such as auto or pointer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property