# css custom cursor showing invalid property value

Tags: css

I am trying to create a custom cursor image on my `<body>` tag .It's not working and Mozilla showing  **invalid property value** . But I can't fix this please check my css :

```
body {
height : 100%;
box-sizing : border-box;
background : transparent;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
cursor: url(icons/cursoricon.png), auto;
}
```

[A screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjjGU.jpg)

Thank You !

Comment: Does it work? See [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url(smiley.gif),url(myBall.cur),auto) have the same "problem".

Comment: here it is working I checked it .

Comment: try to change your second argument from auto to pointer, and also try to resize your image. I think max size for cursor should be something around 32x32px

Comment: Thank you JavaEvgen the problem was the image size .

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307284/cursor-invalid-property-value)?  It seems like changing to the following code may fix your problem, according to [the Mozilla guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).

```
cursor: url(icons/cursoricon.png) 2 2, auto;
```

*Where 2 is optional X and Y coordinates.  Not sure why it fixed this person's problem, as it seems the parameters are optional, but worth trying.

Comment: Hello I checked this and try also but not working check this image [link](http://imgur.com/a/7HHxO)

Comment: Can you try it in other browsers like Chrome and see what happens?  If that doesn't work, can you clarify that your URL is added correctly?  Check this guide out and try replacing your current url with url(https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/131776/isolated/lists/f23a086a9cb2698654d0bc143ec2f83b-pixilated-hourglass-mouse-cursor.png)  or any other online image to see if your path is correct.  Maybe url(./icons/cursoricon.png)?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property

Comment: Thank You for your suggestions but it still not working . It's working on  [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url(smiley.gif),url(myBall.cur),auto) but how ?